# Open FTP URL in browser Android

Tags: android, android-intent, ftp

I want to launch an FTP URL in browser. The URL is similar to this:
ftp://192.168.43.1:2121

```
Intent httpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String url = "ftp://192.168.43.1:2121";
httpIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(httpIntent);
```

This code throws `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException` exception. It seems like browsers are unable to recognise it as a URL. But if we explicitly type  `ftp://192.168.43.1:2121` it opens perfectly in browsers.

I want to list all the browsers of system as choice.

Comment: If you set the type to text/html ?

Comment: Where @blackapps ? I did not understand.

Comment: @HarshitAgarwall you would do this by intent.setType() but thats not going to work. You wont be able to show the OS bottom sheet of Intent options because the result of the request is "No Activity found to handle Intent". It would be rare that users have a FTP app to handle the intent. You will need to specify the class for chrome workaround to make this work unfortunately.

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
`intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");`


Even after specifying these flags it opens a blank chrome without URL.
I just want to pass it the `ftp://url` as string. It should be later decided later by the browser whether it is able to open the URL or not.

Comment: @blackapps I set text/html nothing fruitful happened. The same error was thrown.